# How to add ec2 instance to existing target group in aws using eb extensions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have manually created a load balancer and target group. I am using EBto create ec2 instance. Problem I have is when it spins it up I want it to go into the specified target group which I created manually but I cannot find this option where to set this. Here are the options I have found https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-autoscalinglaunchconfiguration

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you **can't do this**. When you create your EB environment, EB service constructs a **CloudFormation template**. The template defines the required resources, such as Load Balancers and Target Groups. Then EB provisions the stack from the template and all resources in it. Thus it will create **new resources**, it can't use existing ones.

You can **customize this EB template** a bit though. This is done by defining [custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-resources.html) in `.ebextensions` config files. Thus, if there is some hackish way of using existing load balancers and target groups, modification to the EB template through the custom resources is the only way it could maybe be possible.

Comment: Will creating autoscaling group put the instance in target group?

Comment: @shorif2000 Not sure I follow. The point of EB is that you don't manage any of the underlying resources. EB does that. You can only customize them a bit through config files. If you require a complete control, its probably easier to not use EB, and create your own architecture.